# How do I stream my desktop to a webpage via webRTC?

Tags: stream, webrtc

I've done a tutorial that does this exact thing but streams my webcam, and I'd like to stream my desktop instead - more specifically, a certain window. This is to stream a simulation via the local network, but it has to be done on WebRTC. What should I change?

```
 (function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
        vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    navigator.getMedia =    navigator.getDisplayMedia || 
                            navigator.webkitURLGetDisplayMedia || 
                            navigator.mozGetDisplayMedia ||
                            navigator.msGetDisplayMedia;
    //capture video
    navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        Audio: false
    }, function(stream){ 
        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, function(error) {
        //an error occured
        //error.code
    });

 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` and no need vendorUrl here.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
   video: true;
   audio: false;
}, function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e){
       video.play();
    }
});
```